# dynamically change WPF RichTextBox

Tags: wpf, richtextbox

So I'm new to WPF and am looking for some help. All I'm trying to do is change the padding of the current paragraph dependent on capturing a particular key stroke.

The capturing of the key bit is fine and finding the current paragraph is fine but how do change the padding? I presumed it would be something as simple as

```
mainRichTextBox.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Padding.Left = 10d;
```

but it would seem I'm wrong.

If anybody can point me in the right direction that would be great.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd need to set the Padding property to a new instance of Thickness, not modify the current value. Like so:

```
mainRichTextBox.CaretPosition.Paragraph.Padding = new Thickness() { Left = 10d };
```